Cannot enter text into vanilla JavaScript plain-text Lexical
I wrote a small example of the vanilla JavaScript plain-text editor, and I'm not able to place my cursor on the text area and insert text. My question was on what I might need to do to make this example allow text insertions using the cursor. I would like to place my cursor on the contenteditable div and start typing to insert characters.


<h1>Hello, Lexical!</h1>
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true" style="width:100px;"></div>
<script type="module">
// See https://www.npmjs.com/package/lexical documentation.
import * as lexical from 'https://esm.run/lexical';
import { registerPlainText } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@lexical/plain-text@0.14.5/+esm'

const config = {
  namespace: 'MyEditor',
  editable: true,
};
const editor = lexical.createEditor(config);
const contentEditableElement = document.getElementById('editor');
editor.setRootElement(contentEditableElement);
registerPlainText(editor);
editor.setEditable(true);
</script>



I added a JSFiddle here and would be grateful for any suggestions.

style="width:100px" in an HTML tag.  Add more arguments with ; separator.  i.e. style="width:100px;height:40px"  Also, contentEditable="true"

Thanks for the suggestions. Updated.

Using contentEditable already makes the div element editable. The Lexical library creates its own editor instance on top of the existing contentEditable element, blocking the interaction.
Without lexical:
<h1>Hello, Lexical!</h1>
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true" style="width:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>

<script>
    const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
    editor.focus(); // This should allow typing, without lexical
</script>

With lexical:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="module" src="Lexical_code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, Lexical!</h1>
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true" style="width:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>
</body>
</html>

Save this to: Lexical_code.js
// See https://www.npmjs.com/package/lexical documentation.
import * as lexical from 'https://esm.run/lexical';
import { registerPlainText } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@lexical/plain-text@0.14.5/+esm'

// Create the editor configuration
const editorConfig = new EditorConfiguration({
  namespace: 'MyEditor',
  editorState: new EditorState(),
  plugins: [new PlainTextPlugin()],
});

const editor = editorConfig.createEditor();

// Get the DOM, set contentEditable attribute
const contentEditableElement = document.getElementById('editor');

contentEditableElement.contentEditable = true;

editor.applyConfiguration(editorConfig);

// Renders the editor by setting contentEditable

Sorry, I wasn't very clear about imports.

Update: Here's a JSFiddle for example.
Something that I never like doing is relying on external sources for libraries.  If you want to run a standalone directory, download these files to the same directory. (Right click > Save as...)
@lexical/plain-text
lexical@0.14.5
Add them to your Lexical_code.js the same as the JSFiddle shows.
Then, it will even work offline.

Thanks for the information, but unfortunately I'm using Vanilla JavaScript and the code example seems to be React.

@DK2 Updated syntax!
